# OpenCl global work-item operation priority

Tags: opencl

I want to know the priority of index counting for the following code snippets (simple 2 dimensional matrix multiplication routine).

```
kernel void mmul(
   const int N,
   global float* A,
   global float* B,
   global float* C)
 {
     int k;
     int i = get_global_id(0);
     int j = get_global_id(1);
     float tmp;
     if ((i < N) && (j < N))
     {
         tmp = 0.0f;
         for (k = 0; k < N; k++)
             tmp += A[i*N+k] * B[k*N+j];
         C[i*N+j] = tmp;
     }
}
```

If you look inside the for loop with 'k' counter you can see global work-item 'i' and 'j' placed in the same line. I want to know which of them have priority in terms of counting the indexes (eg. 1,2,3,4, ... , n) of 'i' and 'j'. I don't understand how this would work as I am new to OpenCl and I would use nested for loop, if I am just using normal C or Python, for this type of operation.

Can someone explain how the global work-item work?

Thank you.

Comment: Its not exposed to users. But I've seen something like this in amd gpu: a lot of workgroups in a row, a few workgroups mixed, then a lot of workgroups in a row again, them a few mixed again. First workitem may finish last if it gets stuck somewhere because of unknown reasons but number of workitems in-flight is limited so if enough workitems are stuck, work may never end and pc crash. In OpenCL2.0, workitems can spawn workgroups so it may be better for you to control the order.

Comment: So... you are saying the users have to take it for granted how they work? Is this a bad way of coding for matrxi multiplication?

Comment: If you mean "dimensional representation" by "priority", get_global_id(0) is X and get_global_id(1) is Y and if you have given a kernel launch of size (10k/3k) then X scans through 10k and Y scans through 3k.

Answer (score 0):

You should focus more on memory read/write priorities than workitem issuing order. To enforce a priority/order on memory operations, use mem_fence(in-workitem) , barrier(in-workgroup) and even kernels(all workitems sync point). Using deliberate empty for-loops or atomic functions cannot guarantee a memory-write/read priority. Only memory fences/barriers/kernels can.

There is no priority for any workitem(to start/end running) but they are grouped and executed on compute units which have many threads to run them. There is no guarantee that workitem i,j will execute before i+1,j+1 but there is a guarantee they will be executed in same compute unit(with cores sharing L1 cache) if they are in same workgroup(with size of 16,16 for example) when using Nvidia and Amd gpus.

Being executed in same compute unit increases chances of being issued at the same time which is not a priority ofcourse but sharing resources like L1 cache means high performance.

Even in same workgroup, there is no guarantee if a local workitem is issued before some other workitem but they are more likely happening at the same time if they are on same SIMD unit(such as 16-wide parts in Amd gpu).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Then even if they don't have any priority, would the result be the same, as in I would expect ordered indexes (0,1,2,3, ... , N)?

Comment: If any workitem writes to same address as another workitem, it is a race condition and should be solved by any means such as adding fences and kernels. As long as they write to unique addresses, it should work same always(except if you make multiple writes in same workitem without fence). Even using atomics can't enforce an order of memory accesses but a fence can. Whole point of fences/barriers is this. For parallel algorithms, its not important to have an execution order.

Comment: I am sorry but what do you mean by fences? Can you give me an simple example? Thank you.

Comment: mem_fence(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE) separates global memory operations before and after it so they do not get reordered by compiler nor by GPU. barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE) does same thing but it also applies to whole workgroup (such as 256 workitems) so that they all do same thing at the same time. If you separate some writes to another kernel, it makes sure all workitem writes are separated, not just a workgroup.

Comment: Thank you so much. Would you recommend any books or literature about OpenCl? Particularly that deals with numerical analysus. I am having trouble searching for resources, especially with examples.

Comment: Generally forums of amd, nvidia, intel are good. Some pdf files you can find by simply searching a specific algorithm and opencl on google too. Sometimes there are useful blogs with gpu gems, github projecs and similart things,  https://www.researchgate.net/figure/263813578_fig10_OpenCL-parallel-reduction

Comment: Also CUDA related documents are much more crowded so maybe you can check necessary patterns from there, then look for opencl equivalent of necessary commands. An article from year 2000 https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/753d/91cc0747453791179bcdbd234a5b0fbedf52.pdf